# JSomething something = new JSomething().somethingelse;

Tags: java, object, methods

I could swear I saw an object being created this way. What does somethingelse do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking it quite literally, it can be that the class `JSomething` has a field called `somethingelse` that is of type `JSomething`:

```
class JSomething {
    JSomething somethingelse;
}
```

In that case, the reference to the `JSomething` called `somethingelse` inside the `JSomething` can be obtained by the following:

```
JSomething something = new JSomething().somethingelse;
```

However, I suspect that this was seen as part of a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)) called the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) -- where a method call returns an instance of the same type.

For example, take the [`StringBuilder.append`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String)) method -- it returns a [`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Therefore, it would be possible to do the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello").append("World!");
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that new JSomething().somethingelse is just a field access. Maybe a badly written static access of JSomething.somethingelse. For example `Color color = new Color(0).black;` instead of `Color color = Color.black;`.

Answer (score 0):

`somethingelse` in this context would be an instance of JSomething, which is contained within a JSomething.